# How to join two consecutive lines of a file if they meet a certain condition?

Tags: python

** New to Python, sorry **

I'm trying to take a given example file and add only the lines containing "A" or "T" or "G" or "C" (DNA strands) to a list, using a function.

Example file:

***gene1

ATGATGATGGCG

gene2

GGCATATC

CGGATACC

gene3

TAGCTAGCCCGC***

Under gene2 there are two separate lines I need to concatenate using my function.

Here's what I have completed for my function:

```
def create(filename):
    """
    Purpose: Creates and returns a data structure (list) to store data.
    :param filename: The given file
    Post-conditions: (none)
    :return: List of data.
    """
    new_list = []
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    for i in f:
        if not('A' or 'T' or 'G' or 'C') in i:
            new_list = new_list  #Added this so nothing happens but loop cont.
        else:
            new_list.append(i.strip())
    f.close()
    return new_list
```

I need to somehow find parts of the file where there are two consecutive lines of DNA ("GTCA") and join them before adding them to my list.

If done correctly the output when printed should read:

```
['ATGATGATGGCG', 'GGCATATCCGGATACC', 'TAGCTAGCCCGC']
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regexes to the rescue!

```
import re

def create(filename):
    dna_regex = re.compile(r'[ATGC]+')
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return dna_regex.findall(f.read().replace('\n', '')))

new_list = []
new_list += create("gene_file.txt")
```

It's important to note that this implementation in particular might get a false positive if the `gene` lines contains an A, T, G, or C.

What this does is it takes in the whole file, removes the newlines, and then finds all of the sequences containing only A, T, G, or C and returns them.

Comment: Nice approach. Good hint for the possible drawback, while given the file structure where non-DNA lines are simply of the form `gene#N` this should be a proper solution imo.

Comment: Just a question, is there anyway to add each of the results to my empty list and then return that list? Still kinda new so I might be missing something.

Comment: @Matthew S Yep! I updated the example to add it to the empty list, but you can also assign it to the variable directly with: `new_list = create("gene_file.txt")` and the result will be the same (unless you're trying to take multiple files and do this, in which case you'll need to append them like in the example).

Comment: Ah, I mis-spoke, my bad. Don't use `append()` otherwise you will get a list of lists. use `+=` to concatenate the two lists, like in the example.

Comment: If I try and do it this way it returns a list of lists. Can I do it like this and get a regular list?                                                                                                                                    --------------                                                                                                                         
    with open(filename, 'r') as f: -----
        new_list.append(dna_regex.findall(f.read().replace('\n', ''))) ----- 
    return new_list

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)s to check if a line is a DNA line, i.e. consists of the letters ACGT only:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    new_list = []
    concat = False
    for line in f:
        if set(line.strip()) == {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'}:
            if concat:
                new_list[-1] += line.strip()
            else:
                new_list.append(line.strip())
            concat = True
        else:
            concat = False

# ['ATGATGATGGCG', 'GGCATATCCGGATACC', 'TAGCTAGCCCGC']
```

Answer (score 0):

If we can assume that each DNA section is prefixed by one line, we can take advantage of the `takewhile` function that'll group the DNA lines:

```
from itertools import takewhile

DNA_CHARS = ('A', 'T', 'G', 'C')
lines = ['gene1', 'ATGATGATGGCG', 'gene2', 'GGCATATC', 'CGGATACC', 'gene3', 'TAGCTAGCCCGC']

input_lines = iter(lines[1:])
dna_lines = []

while True:
    dna_line = ''.join(takewhile(lambda l: any(dna_char in l for dna_char in DNA_CHARS),
                                  input_lines))
    if not dna_line:
        break
    dna_lines.append(dna_line)
```